# Handling Mongoose `populate()` Functionality in Wrapper Function

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

In our Node/MongoDB project we have a wrapper function we use for all `findOne()` operations in order to handle aspects like permissions centrally. The problem I'm running into involves Mongoose `populate()` functionality.

Because we're using a wrapper function on all our findOne()'s, I need to define the `populate()` logic at the wrapper function level. But because the number of `populate()`s I'll need varies from function to function, I have to end up writing conditional statements in our wrapper function, like this:

```
 if (mongooseModelObject.modelName === "Staff" && this.parameters.populateArray) {
    return await mongooseModelObject
      .findOne(searchObject, options)
      .setOptions({ authLevel: this.permissionString, permissions: true })
      .populate(this.parameters.populateArray[0].targetId, this.parameters.populateArray[0].limit)
      .populate(this.parameters.populateArray[1].targetId, this.parameters.populateArray[1].limit)
      .populate(this.parameters.populateArray[2].targetId, this.parameters.populateArray[2].limit)
      .populate(this.parameters.populateArray[3].targetId, this.parameters.populateArray[3].limit)
      .populate(this.parameters.populateArray[4].targetId, this.parameters.populateArray[4].limit)
      .populate(this.parameters.populateArray[5].targetId, this.parameters.populateArray[5].limit);
  } else {
    return await mongooseModelObject.findOne(searchObject, options).setOptions({ authLevel: this.permissionString, permissions: true });
  }
```

What would make this much simpler is if I could pass an array to `populate()`. That way, whether I need to use `populate()` on one property or five, it will still work.

Is this something Mongoose allows for? Or do I have to chain `populate()` one by one like in my included code? if not, I'm open to other suggestions as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could loop on the populateArray

```
 await this.parameters.populateArray.reduce((tmp, {
    targetId,
    limit,
  }) => tmp.populate(targetId, limit), mongooseModelObject
  .findOne(searchObject, options)
  .setOptions({
    authLevel: this.permissionString,
    permissions: true,
  }));
```

---

According to [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate) documentation, you can't pass an array to it.

Comment: Using `reduce()` for this and looping is an excellent suggestion. Many thanks, @Gregory.